# Manage Emails Sent When Changing Participant Status

Tags: civievent, email

When you change a participants status on the back end an email is sent.  Sometimes you may not want an email to be sent to the participant.  Is there a way to suppress these emails? Is there a setting I am missing to control when these emails are sent?

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid the answer to your question is: "No you're not missing a setting." CiviCRM will send out emails for bulk 'registration status' updates automatically with no way to stop it.

For some projects - we'll use a simple Drupal `buildForm hook` for other backend registrations/updates (below) - but this does not help with the bulk actions.

```
function mydrupalmodule_civicrm_buildForm( $formName, &$form ) {
  if ( $formName == 'CRM_Event_Form_Participant' ) {
     // please no - really - yes - no confirmation emails...
    $form->assign('email', '');
    $form->assign('batchEmail', '');
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this still the case? Is there no workaround. I'm seeing this on a site using 4.6.current and its a major PITA.